# load external xml feed in drupal based on login credentials

Tags: feeds, users, database

We are asked to provide a secure RSS or XML feed to a Drupal based website. The idea is that we provide some basic information about our service (e.g. # of unread messages) based on their Drupal login credentials. Our service can be set up any way needed.

Are there any modules available that can use native Drupal authentication to login to another web service and load the provided information onto the page?